# My file has 5 items when I enter 4, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my program requires the user to enter whatever they want to be in a text file (I entitled it chapter14file.txt). Once they are finished, they are supposed to enter "done". So I create a few print statements to make sure everything is ok. If I run this program and get to the print statement in question (last line), it will show more than what I entered. If I entered on separate lines:

1

2

Test

3

done

Now I'm done. So I enter "done." It gets to the print statement and shows this:
['1', '2', 'Test', '3', '']

So it is important to know that I am tasked to convert user inputs to a list. That's why items are in the square brackets.

```
chapter14file = open ("chapter14file.txt", "w+")

while True:
    user_item = str (input ("Please enter what you would like to be added to chapter14file.txt. Type 'done' when you are finished. ") )
    if user_item.upper() == "DONE":
        break
    else:
        chapter14file.write (user_item + ",")

chapter14file.close()
items_from_file = (open ("chapter14file.txt").read())
items_list = items_from_file.split(",")
items_list_capital = [ elem.upper() for elem in items_list ] #Converts each element of the list to only have capital letters, no lowercase letters. Makes the search case insensitive.
print (items_from_file, items_list, items_list_capital)
```

Expected (sticking with previous example): ['1', '2', 'Test', '3']

Actual: ['1', '2', 'Test', '3', '']

Note: When I am talking about the results, '' specifically, between the two little apostrophes there is nothing.

Comment: I dont like keeping files open longer than need be.  I think it would be better for you to store the items in an array, and then after DONE, dump the contents to a file.  You cant then format the items however need be, such as doing `",".join(arr)` which would create a comma delimited string.

Answer (score 2):

This is where the issue is:

```
chapter14file.write (user_item + ",")
```

You're appending that `,` to each of the entries. So the last entry ends up looking like:

```
a,b,c,
```

When you take this string and split it at `,` - you end up with an empty string due to the last `,` character.

You can fix it by either removing the last `,` or by stripping away the empty string.

Comment: Part of the assignment is to "write the item concatenated with a comma to the file." So I do need the comma, how would I go about splitting the items without having the empty string?

Comment: When writing the file use `join` instead of concatenation.

Comment: Example of join: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep the same format for "," but try something like this instead for the while statement:
y=0;
while True:
    user_item = str (input ("Please enter what you would like to be added to chapter14file.txt. Type 'done' when you are finished. ") )

```
if user_item.upper() == "DONE":
    break
if y>=1:
    chapter14file.write ("," + user_item)    
else:
    chapter14file.write (user_item) 
    y+=1
```

Using a varible y to find the first value.